# determine force from a hammer to pull out a nail

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, forces

[image]

Hi 
the force from the hammer is 5,4 * F according to my book .. How did they calculate that ? Should not it be 27 * F 
thanks

Comment: centimeter-Newtons is not a unit of force.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do a torque balance around the point of rotation. The applied force gives a torque of $27*F$. The nail gives a torque of $-5*f_{nail}$. These torques must sum to zero, so solving for the nail force gives $f_{nail}=(27/5)F=5.4*F$